# predict.lm() used mean value of the group instead of the predicted value

Tags: r

Good afternoon R users,

I have an issue using a predict.lm() function to predict a value for my DV from mean group values of three IVs.

My DV:

- Pre_TimeinSB_Troiano2008_100cpm_30min_plusBouts_pd - i.e., the time spent in continuous sitting lasting at least 30 min (min/day)

My IV's:

- "Pre_Time_Copeland2009_ST_25cpm_pd" – accelerometer wear time (min/day)
- "Pre_SED_Troiano2008_pd" – total sedentary time (min/day)
- "Pre_TotalMVPA_Copeland2009_ST_25cpm_pd – total moderate to vigorous physical activity (min/day)

I want to predict the value of my DV from the mean sample values for each of these predictors.

The issue:
The predicted value equals to the mean value of my DV not to the predicted values as calculated below based on regression coefficients from the output

My R version:

> R Studio version: 2022.12.0+353 (2022.12.0+353)
> R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31)
> Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)
> Running under: macOS Monterey 12.6.2
>
> Attached packages
> attached base packages:
> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
>
> other attached packages:
> [1] lubridate_1.9.2 forcats_1.0.0   stringr_1.5.0   dplyr_1.1.0     purrr_1.0.1     readr_2.1.4     tidyr_1.3.0
> [8] tibble_3.2.0    ggplot2_3.4.1   tidyverse_2.0.0 modeldata_1.1.0

My code:

```
   library(tidyverse)
   library(modeldata)

   setwd("/Users/Datasets/Manuscript")
   d<-read.csv('PREDICTORS.csv',sep=',',header = T)

    mean_time=mean(d$Pre_Time_Copeland2009_ST_25cpm_pd)
    mean_sed_tr=mean(d$Pre_SED_Troiano2008_pd)
    mean_mvpa_cop=mean(d$Pre_TotalMVPA_Copeland2009_ST_25cpm_pd)
    mean_mvpa_tr=mean(d$Pre_TotalMVPA_Troiano2008_pd)
    mean_tsb30min=mean(d$Pre_TimeinSB_Troiano2008_100cpm_30min_plusBouts_pd)

    modstate3 <- reformulate(c("Pre_Time_Copeland2009_ST_25cpm_pd",    
    "Pre_SED_Troiano2008_pd","Pre_TotalMVPA_Copeland2009_ST_25cpm_pd"),
    response="Pre_TimeinSB_Troiano2008_100cpm_30min_plusBouts_pd")
    reg3 = lm(modstate3, d)
    r3 = resid(reg3)
    new3 <- data.frame(Pre_Time_Copeland2009_ST_25cpm_pd=c(mean_time), 
    Pre_SED_Troiano2008_pd=c(mean_sed_tr),      
    Pre_TotalMVPA_Copeland2009_ST_25cpm_pd=c(mean_mvpa_cop))
    p3=predict.lm(reg3, newdata=new3)
    p3a <- as.numeric(p3)
    print(p3a)
    reg3$coefficients
```

Output

```
print(p3a)
#> [1] 202.596
format(p3a, digits = 10)
#> [1] "202.5960184"
reg3$coefficients
(Intercept)             Pre_Time_Copeland2009_ST_25cpm_pd 
103.0348261                -0.9109195 
Pre_SED_Troiano2008_pd      Pre_TotalMVPA_Copeland2009_ST_25cpm_pd 
1.3963774                        1.4143874 
print(mean_time)
[1] 867.0451
print(mean_sed_tr)
[1] 587.5502
print(mean_mvpa_cop)
[1] 48.73319
print(mean_tsb30min)
[1] 202.596
y3 = 103.0348261 + (-0.9109195*867.0451) + (1.3963774*587.5502) + (1.4143874*48.73319)
print(y3)
[1] 202.596
format(y3, digits = 10)
[1] "202.5959677"
```

I am not sure why the mean value for the DV is printed as predicted values instead of the true predicted values given the regression coefficients and means for my predictors.

I would appreciate any ideas that could help me solve this issue.

Thank you,

Dominika

I tried:

1. predict(reg3, newdata=new3)
2. spelling out the regression model:
   `reg3 = lm(Pre_TimeinSB_Troiano2008_100cpm_30min_plusBouts_pd ~ Pre_Time_Copeland2009_ST_25cpm_pd + Pre_SED_Troiano2008_pd + Pre_TotalMVPA_Copeland2009_ST_25cpm_pd, d)`
3. creating a vector with 119 (my sample size) values that included means for each predictor.
4. a simpler model with mean wear time as the single predictor

Options #1, 2, and 4 yielded the same result as the original
Option #3 did not work.

Comment: Your `newdata` consists of the mean values for your predictors, so the mean of the response is exactly what you'd expect the prediction to be.

Comment: Please don't use smart quotes `”` in posted code.